# Best practice of handling many single functions

Tags: c++, class

I have many small functions which every is doing a single thing like for example:
pingServer, checkUserValidAccount, countDistance.

It is not worth of wrapping every function into single class.

What is the best practice in c++ to handle such a different many small functions?

Maybe writing some class called Helpers like for example NetworkHelpers?

Answer (score 6):

Placing them in a `namespace` is an option. I don't see the need for a class. An instance of a class is mean to represent a state, but you're describing a bunch of free functions, so a stateless system.

"It is not worth of wraping every function into single class." - this is not a valid argument for making the decision not to write a class. A class can have a single member and a single method, but if there is logic behind it, you should write it.

If your functions and your logic mandates the use of a class, where your functions have the same logic but operate differently depending on the object, by all means, write a class. If your sole purpose is to group the functions together, when their logic doesn't really rely on the same instance of a class, group them in a namespace.

An example based on your question:

```
namespace NetworkHelpers
{
   //free function, use a namespace
   bool pingServer(std::string hostname);
}

//alternative, where the object has a state:
class ServerConnection
{
   std::string _hostname;
public:
   NetworkHelpersClass(std::string hostname) 
   { 
      _hostname = hostname; 
   }
   bool pingServer()
   { 
      return NetworkHelpersNamespace::pingServer(_hostname); 
   }
};
```

As you can see, inside the namespace, the function doesn't depend on anything other than the parameter.

Inside the class, since it has a state and you create an object for each server (so similar behavior, yet different depending on the object), you call the function with no parameters as the object has a state.

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Where by "function" you mean "class"? :)

Comment: @themel, yes, I edited my answer just as soon as I hit the post button. :)

Comment: I would add a further note: when it comes to choosing the namespace, it's a good habit to put the function in the same namespace (not `std`) as one of its arguments (choice to be made here, obviously). If it does not take any argument that lives in a namespace (except from `std`), then consider the namespace of its return type. If there is no namespace invovled at all... then create one.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some languages, C++ does not require that you put every function in a class. If you have functions that don't belong in a class, put them in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If I may add another best practice other than namespaces: group your functions in DLLs minding their dependencies.
Avoid circular linking and create low-level libraries with the smallest number of dependencies as possible.